# How to template full classes in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am confused with templates. I have two full classes; Special_Integer class and Special_String class. They both have one common class as a superclass and
one special class.

```
class Special_Integer: public Internal_Integer, public Message_System

class Special_String: public Internal_String, public Message_System
```

I only need to execute the functions which are common to them such as

```
Special_Integer.sendMessage()
Special_String.sendMessage()
```

which are in Message_System class

Now I want to create a std::list or std::vector in such a way that I do not have to create two list like

```
std::list< boost::shared_ptr<Special_Integer> > exampleList;
std::list< boost::shared_ptr<Special_String> > exampleList2;
```

but if I could template them in one list like

```
std::list< boost::shared_ptr<template_Type> > exampleList;
```

I this possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in this case you don't really need templates. Both of your classes share a base class, so just use polymorphism

```
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Message_System>> exampleList;
```

Then if there is some `virtual` method in the base class

```
virtual void Message_System::sendMessage();
```

The derived classes can `override` those

```
void Special_Integer::sendMessage() override;
void Special_String::sendMessage() override;
```

Then when you call each `sendMessage`, the correct derived method will be called polymorphically.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: A follow up question; if I want to run a non common function, I am doing dynamic_cast like boost::shared_ptr <Special_String> foo = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<Special_String>(*it); 
if (foo){
}

Comment: @user1566277 Yes that is a correct method to check if the cast is correct. Then you can call methods that are specific to one derived class or the other.

Comment: Thanks. But the code looks ugly. Consider it doing for a dozen of types. Everytime I need to declare new variable (foo) check it and then inside block execute. I think I cannot create a common execution block as for each type I have to do a dynamic_cast. So basically lots of if statements and code that looks similar as it is calling same function in every block for different subclass.